# php insert string into array with key value pair

Tags: php, arrays

**Edit: Provided Answer**

Here is my loop, that will print `day of month = # of entries per day`

```
$count = 0;
foreach($date as $dateKey=> $dateVal) {
   echo $dateVal."=".$count;

       foreach($Posts as $PostKey => $PostVal){

        if($dateVal == $numVal) {
           echo $dateVal."=".$numVal['count'];
       }
   }

}
```

will print this

```
01 = 0
02 = 0
03 = 12
04 = 0
05 = 13
06 = 0
07 = 16
08 = 0
```

How can push it inside an array with key value pair and make it like this.

```
$arr[01 => 0, 02 => 0, 03 => 12 ...]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Made it work with this

```
$date = count($date)
$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $date; $i++ ){
    $arr[$i]['date'] = $date[$i]; //insert in array
    $arr[$i]['count'] = 0; //if no entry for e.g(day 1) insert 0

    foreach($numbers as $PostKey => $PostVal){
        if($arr[$i]['date'] == date('d',strtotime($PostVal['date']))) {
            $arr[$i]['count'] = $PostVal['count'];
        }
    }
}
```

will print this way

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [count] => 1 [date] => 2017-11-07 ) [1] => Array ( [count] => 1 [date] => 2017-11-09 ) [2] => Array ( [count] => 2 [date] => 2017-11-10 ) [3] => Array ( [count] => 1 [date] => 2017-11-11 ) )
```

Comment: *"How can push it inside an array ..."* -- don't print the values, [put them into an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating an array and setting  its key and value as shown below:

```
$count = 0;
$arr = array();
foreach($date as $dateKey=> $dateVal) {
   echo $dateVal."=".$count;

       foreach($numbers as $numKey => $numVal){

        if($dateVal == $numVal) {
           $arr[$dateVal] =$numVal['count'];
       }
   }

}
```